# Summing up dseg registers

Tags: assembly

Alright, so for example I have this code (using TASM and Dosbox):

```
dseg    segment
        a DB 2
        b DB 3
dseg ends

cseg segment
assume cs:cseg, ds:dseg
    Start: add a, b
cseg ends
end Start
```

So the program should add b (3) to a (2) and to sum to to 5. Problem is it gives me this error: "Need register in expression". How could this be solved?

Comment: Variables in memory are not registers. Registers are AX, BX and so on, and they don't reside in memory. They're right on the CPU chip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The x86 family of processors generally does not support direct operations on multiple memory operands - one of the operands must be loaded into a register, e.g.:

```
mov al, a
add b, al
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I did in the first place, but hoped it could be somehow shortened. I guess it can't.

Comment: I have another question if you can answer: How can I fix the "relative jump out of range" error without inbetween jumps? Like stretching the jump?

Comment: Since the very early x86 versions, there are two sizes of relative jumps - the one using a signed single-byte offset is known as a `short` jump whereas the one with a signed 32-bit offset is known as a `near` jump (for historical reasons). Evidently I no longer remember exactly how TASM does it, because I was under the impression that it automatically sized jumps correctly. Are you specifying a size (short/near)?

Comment: Please post a separate question on this with the associated code.